# BoxStore DbMaxReadersExceededException: How to resolve for background RxJava threads? - Exception still occurs

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I know this subject has been discussed here before, and we have utilized past conversations to attempt to resolve the DbMaxReadersExceededException that we are still experiencing.  We are using version 2.5.1 of ObjectBox.  We are also, heavily, using RxJava threads while manipulating our BoxStore DB.  At any moment in time, potentially a handful of RxJava threads are running, accessing the DB.  Threads are constantly spawning, executing and terminating.

This is a very "non-standard" use of Android.  Our App is running on a non-cell phone device, that sits on a wall and is expected to be available 24x7.  95% of the RxJava threads that access the BoxStore DB are short lived, get in / get out threads, that retrieve information and present to the device user.  We do have a few longer lived background RxJava threads, that talk to an external DB over the internet to keep the local DB up to date.  But these threads to spawn, execute and terminate.  Theses threads run in the background at regular intervals.  These background threads are not associated with a Fragment nor Activity; therefore the common way of cleaning up, using a CompositeDisposable, is not utilized.

We are seeing that readers are accumulating, despite many attempts to resolve the situation.  We have also noticed that threads, that have run to termination, marked as isAlive and appear to be part of the RxJava thread pool, also accumulate.  We have observed this using Thread.getAllStackTraces() and printing out this information regularly.  Separate issue I am not trying to resolve with this post (I am concentrating on the DbMaxReadersExceededException issue, but they may be related).

The readers accumulate as the result of .find() calls on a Query that is build; based upon analysis of when a reader occurs.  That is not surprising, but sometimes a .find() causes a new reader and sometimes it does not.  I do not understand this behavior, and I am not sure if that is a telling sign or not.  But it does result in the accumlation of active readers everytime the RxJava thread that accessed a given Box is invoked.

Any help / assistance offered will be greatly appreciated.  Please ask any questions about anything that I may have accidental left out.

Things that we have tried, based upon other posts that I have read, include:

- Collect Disposables from RxJava background threads and dispose

  We have tried collecting the Disposable generated by the .subscribe() from these background threads, and added a timer to .dispose() of them sometime (5 seconds) after the thread that was using this object terminates (run to completion).
- Utilized BoxStore.diagnose()

  We have written code to utilize BoxStore.diagnose() to be able to periodically watch the reader accumulation.
- Tried BoxStore.closeThreadResources()

  We have added BoxStore.closeThreadResources() calls when an RxJava thread terminates to cleanup any BoxStore resources that may be active.
- Tried Box.closeThreadResources()

  We have tried adding Box.closeThreadResources() calls closer to when the Box is accessed in order to access and then clean up ASAP.
- Tried breaking down .method() sequence and added .close() calls to itermediate objects

  We have tried breaking down the .method() call sequence that terminates with the .find() call and then .close() or .closeThreadResources() the intermediate objects along the way.
- Tried combinations of the above

  We have tried a combination of all of the above.
- Wrote method to be able to monitor RxJava threads using Thread.getAllStackTraces() - RxJava threads seem to accumulate

  We have written a method that helps us monitor RxJava threads using Thread.getAllStackTraces().
- We have tried to manually invoke the Garbage Collector

  We added code, after the .dispose(), mentioned above, to cause a manual Garbage Collection (System.gc()).

As far as I know, we have tried every suggestion that I have seen posted on this and other forms, regarding this issue.  We are at a loss as to what to do or try next.  I did see something about a package called RxObjectBox, but I have not pursued this any further.

Should we:

- Look at restructuring our RxJava thread access?
- Do we need to look closer at RxObjectBox?
- Is there a known problem with ObjectBox 2.5.1 that we should be using a later version?
- What haven't we tried that we should?

Comment: I don't know BoxStore. Try using an `ExecutorService` with a limited number of worker threads handed to `Schedulers.from`; instead of `Schedulers.io()`.

Comment: Update on the above suggestion:

I tried the above suggestion for a limited number of RxJava threads (we have 100's) that are known to cause an increase in readers.  Unfortunately, unless I did something wrong, both the overall thread count and the active BoxStore reader count have increased.  So, unless I did something wrong, that did not work.

Comment: Without seeing the code, we can't say. Did you share a `Schedulers.from(executor)` or did you recreate it, and the `Executor` every time when you use `subscribeOn`/`observeOn`?

Comment: First, thank you for your help akarnokd.  It is greatly appreciated.  My first try was to use a 2 thread pool that I created.  One Scheduler was handed to the subscribeOn(), the second was handed to observeOn().  The ExecutorService pool was recreated every time I entered the method that had the BoxStore Reader issue.  This code had the results listed above.

Based upon your latest comments, I re-did the code to use a single thread pool ExecutorService for both the subscribeOn() and observeOn().  I also created the single thread pool once at class instantiation time.

This seems to work.

Comment: I will do further testing, but the thread count definitely reduced.  The only "bad" thin though, is it had no effect on the BoxStore Reader count, so the exception will still be thrown.  There is obvious benefits, but doesn't solve my ultimate problem unfortunately.